# Rest service does not accept the given post althoug it is annotated as multipart

Tags: java, rest, cxf, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an apache cxf rest service where on method needs to receive an image, and some other string data. For that I created a service definition like this.

```
@Override
@POST
@Path("attach/{formId}/{instanceId}")
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
@Produces("application/xml")
public UploadResult attach(@FormParam("username") @WebParam(name = "username") String user,
                           @FormParam("password") @WebParam(name = "password") String password,
                           @PathParam("formId") @WebParam(name = "formId") String formId,
                           @PathParam("instanceId") @WebParam(name = "instanceId") String instanceId,
                           @FormParam("group") @WebParam(name = "group") String group,
                           @FormParam("data") @WebParam(name = "data") byte[] data,
                           @FormParam("metadata") @WebParam(name = "metadata") byte[] metadata)
    throws PDProcessingException,
    PDSecurityException
{
    return svc.attach( user, password, formId, instanceId, group, data, metadata );
}
```

Now I tried to use this method with my clients but it wont work and returns a 415 unsupported mediatype. I tried it with the Wiztools.org RestClient and with a test client code which calls the method like this

```
public static String attach(String username, String hashedpassword, String attachmentUri) {

    String retVal = "";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.101.27/pdxapi/service/rest/ClientApp/attach/DE_OJ_PDIX_TEST/SRSQS.0");
    try {
        String hashedPw = DigestFactory.calculatePasswordHash(hashedpassword);

        File file = new File(attachmentUri);
        if (file == null || !file.exists()){
            throw new RuntimeException("there is no file " + attachmentUri);
        }
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("username", new StringBody(username));
        entity.addPart("password", new StringBody(hashedPw));
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file,"image/jpeg");
        entity.addPart("data",fileBody);

        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        if (response.getEntity() == null){

            retVal = "";                
        }
        else{
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }               
            retVal = sb.toString();             
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

I tried also the the annotation @Consumes("multipart/form-data") but with the same result.
Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I solved it by changing the method and using a MultiPartBody as described here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html

Answer (score 0):

http://tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/
add required jar files to your project